# c++ equivalent unsigned atithmetic in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a c++ snippet to java. It is very simple.
I have a byte input with value `-121`.
There is a routine that converts it to unsigned integer and converts it to string using base 16 and I get `"ffffffffffffff87"`

I am not sure how to get the same string in Java. 
This is what I have tried

```
byte b = -121;
int iVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE + b + 1;
String str = Integer.toString(iVal, 16);
// prints "7fffff87"
```

How can I get the same string as c++ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `Long.toHexString(b)`.  This returns `ffffffffffffff87` when `b` is `-121`.